# Stop Internet Explorer from casting my index to an int

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm indexing through a form with something like:

```
var i = 0;
var s = new String( i+'.prop');
var v = document.formName[s].value;
```

but what I get is actually:

```
document.formName[0].value
```

it appears that my index value "0.prop" is getting cast to an int, only in Internet Explorer (8)

any ideas on how to stop that?

UPDATE:  here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn7nv/) that exhibits the problem.  Should return '111', but it returns foo in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT! according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) NAME attributes must start with a letter not a number...

so adapting your html and using

```
var i = 0;
var s = 'prop_'+i;
var v = document.formName[s].value;
```

will work (I also updated the fiddle)

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPEv3)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPEv3/ works for me... or did I missed something regarding your question?

Comment: curious, that works for me.  I sliced what I thought was the problem code out of a bigger chunk.  Let me go further up the chain.  Thanks for your answer and follow up.

Comment: you could flag / vote this answer as an answer for this particular question, if you want to :)

Comment: updated question to include a fiddle that exhibits the problem.  +tobias, just needed some more elements in the form to exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the toString() method:

```
var i = 0;
var s = i.toString() + '.prop';

typeof(s) === string // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
var s = new String(''+i+'.prop');
```

Or

```
var s = new String( i.toString()+'.prop');
```

Comment: the String constructor is not needed here

Comment: I didn't add that in there, I just copied the OP's code..so how about removing that negative vote?